# Remove or replace field from an object lookup list in related list section

Tags: related-list, list-view, relatedlistnew

I need to remove or replace a field from an Object lookup in Related List Quick Links section like below

[image]

This section doesn't let us customize the fields like **"Select Fields to Display"**. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the page layout. Follow the below steps:-

setup | Object Manager | select the object( In your case, it will be opportunity) | Page Layout | Open your page layout | Go to the related list | click on the wrench icon | select the field you want to display | save

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many many Thanks @sanket. It woked.